# Restrict access to part of Joomla articles with OS Membership Pro

Tags: joomla-3.4, extensions, acl, membership

I'm very new to Joomla, and I'm currently trying to Restrict access to part of Joomla articles using membership pro.

I trying to follow the guide listed here

http://membershipprodoc.joomservices.com/resources-access-restriction

I've published the plugin, step 1. Step is to use the syntax mprestriction ids="1"}The text you want to hide must be inserted between here{/mprestriction} to restrict access to the article to subscribers of the plan you want. Below is the explanation of the syntax:
ids="1" mean only users have active subscription of Plan with ID = 1 can see the text. You can change 1 to ID of any plans you want
You can allow subscribers from different subscription plans to see this text, just separate the plan ids by comma. For example, If you enter ids="1,3" for example, subscribers from plan with ID = 1 or ID = 3 will be able to see the text and so on....

But I'm not sure how to do this.

Is anyone familiar doing this sort of thing? With Membership Pro or any other application?

Thanks

Carlton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read carefully and make sure you understand the documentation of the software you use.

I would strongly suggest you, to install the extension on test joomla site, and learn how to use it, before you mess with your live site:

- a clean install will generally let you play and test the features, try the various configuration options and learn, while you will be more sure if something that is happening is because there is a bug, instead of you doing it wrong, or because of a conflict with another extension.
- testing on a clone of your live site, will help you create and test the configuration the fits to your exact needs.

Now regarding this particular question of restricting part of Joomla articles, all the documentation says is to add these shortcodes inside your articles, to wrap the part of the article that you want to be accessible only by subscribers. It's looks like pretty self-explanatory.

**Article Example**

```
ARTICLE CONTENT AVAILABLE TO EVERYONE... 
{mprestriction ids="1"} ARTICLE CONTENT AVAILABLE TO SUBSCRIBRERS
ONLY SUBSCRIBERS OF SUBSCRIPTION WITH ID 1 WILL BE ABLE TO SEE IT. {/mprestriction} 
ARTICLE CONTENT AVAILABLE TO EVERYONE...
```

Probably, you will need to have enabled some plugins that would ship with the component and of course all the other essential configurations, to have the extension ready and in charge of who will be accessing what.