# Joomla Site Crashed - due to RSMembership

Tags: joomla-3.4

I'm facing a disaster. I recently installed RSMembership (based on a suggestion from a member from this site). Everything appeared to be working well, until I discovered that everyone was able to access my articles whether they were registered or not. I therefore decided to uninstall RSMembership (big mistake). As result, my site has totally crashed. If you attempt to enter my site at www.keylooplabs.com you will get the following

[image: access error]

When I attempt to login to the site I get the following error:

[image: joomla login]

I have been frantically trying to get in touch with support at RSMembership but they don't appear to work on the weekends. They're website suggests following the guide https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsmembership-user-guide/installing-and-uninstalling/manually-uninstall-rsmembership.html if a regular uninstall fails.

I would be so grateful to a community member if they are highly experienced with these matters to help me.

I would be willing to make a small contribution to a charity of your desire if you were able help resolve this. I can't begin to tell you how upsetting this is.

Thanks

Carlton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my answer to your other recent question on [how to restrict access to articles](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/16943/restrict-access-to-part-of-joomla-articles), I wrote:

> I would strongly suggest you, to install the extension on test joomla site, and learn how to use it, before you mess with your live site...

Probably, the error you are getting now is because there are some dependencies or calls left behind after uninstalling the extension. Having configured the website to work in a membership fashion (whatever this configuration was, right or wrong) and then simply go and uninstall this, it 's very likely that the website will crash.

Generally is a bad practice to experiment on live sites by installing/uninstalling software, or doing any other kind of development.

Following this documentation: https://www.rsjoomla.com/support/documentation/rsmembership-user-guide/installing-and-uninstalling/manually-uninstall-rsmembership.html

Go in your PHPmyAdmin and perform those queries. But first make sure you get a new back of the database at its current state.

Comment: FFRewin, luckily I took your advice a few posts back and did a backup. Everything has been restored now... thanks